# How to find a power function, representing a model for data?

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling

In a calculus textbook by late James Stewart I encountered an exercise to find a power function, as a mathematical model approximately representing data:

```
The table shows the number N of species of reptiles and
amphibians inhabiting Caribbean islands and the area A of
the island in square miles. 

a) Use a power function to model N as a function of A.

Island      A        N 
Saba        4        5
Monserrat   40       9
Puerto Rico 3,459    40
Jamaica     4,411    39
Hispaniola  29,418   84
Cuba        44,218   76
```

The confusing thing is that in the previous pages of the textbook there were no explanation of how to do it, except using special software like Mathematica© and only for a linear model.

**The correct answer from the textbook is: $N = 3.1046 A^{0.308}$**

Could anyone explain to me, please, how this answer was obtained?

I myself found another answer $N = A^{-2.47295*10^{-6} * A + 0.504732}$

by finding $log_A N$ for every item in the table (except the first one, which looked far out of order) and then finding the linear regression for these values with Mathematica©'s tool `Fit` (which I took as the exponent value for my function):

```
Island      A        N(real)   N(the textbook's func.) N(my func.)
Saba        4        5         4.75817                 2.01314
Monserrat   40       9         9.6703                  6.43358
Puerto Rico 3,459    40        38.1946                 57.0098
Jamaica     4,411    39        41.1645                 63.0608
Hispaniola  29,418   84        73.848                  85.1851
Cuba        44,218   76        83.724                  68.6738
```

The right answer definitely looks more close to the reality, so could anyone, please, explain to me, how it was obtained?

Comment: This one is even better $N=4.238 A^{0.281}-2.269$ look at the results
$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
A & N \\
\hline
 4 & 3.98762 \\
 40 & 9.68023 \\
 3459 & 39.5724 \\
 4411 & 42.5308 \\
 29418 & 74.0867 \\
 44218 & 83.3508 \\
\end{array}$$
It's a function of *Mathematica* called NonlinearModelFit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to log-linearize your relation, i.e.

$N = \alpha A^\beta \iff \ln N =\ln\alpha +\beta \ln A$

If one considers a $6\times2$ matrix $\boldsymbol{X}$ which horizontally stacks a $6\times1$ vector of $1$s with a $6\times1$ vector of $\ln A$, know that computing $(\boldsymbol{X}^{'}\boldsymbol{X})^{-1}\boldsymbol{X}^{'}\ln N$ yields the following $2\times1$ hyper-coefficient $(\ln \alpha, \beta)'$. In matrix terms,

$\ln N = \boldsymbol{X}(\ln \alpha, \beta)' + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$

where $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$ is a $6\times1$ vector of errors ($0$-centered thanks to the implication of $\ln \alpha$ in the estimation. Doing so yields $e^{\ln \alpha} = \alpha = 3.10462040170919$ and $\beta=0.308044235476563$.

---

Note that $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$ is conceptually not due to the quality of your approximation approach, but is due to the intrinsic stochastic nature of the phenomenon of study. A contrario the vector of residuals, $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}$, as it stands in $\widehat{\ln N} - \boldsymbol{X}\widehat{(\ln \alpha, \beta)'} = \widehat{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}$, entails both $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$ and something more which depends on the estimation procedure.

Answer (score 1):

$$N=\alpha A^{\beta}$$

We want to figure out what is $\alpha$ and $\beta$. By taking logarithm. We obtain

$$\ln N = \ln \alpha + \beta \ln A$$

Regress $\ln N$ on $\ln A$. The slope is $\beta$ and the intercept $c=\ln \alpha$.

$$\alpha = \exp(c)$$